# How do make an older python3.x the default in Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I've got the `python@3.9`, `python@3.10` and `python@3.11` packages installed.  When I type `python3` it uses the 3.11 one.  Using `brew unlink -v <package>` and `brew link -v <package>` I can see that the 3.11 version somehow knows that it should create a `python3` link and the other two know that they shouldn't.  How can I tell these packages that I want the 3.9 version to create this link rather than the 3.11 version?